# Probability of $6$ tickets winning $3$ out of $8$ lucky draw prizes among $650$ tickets

Tags: probability

What is the probability of $6$ tickets winning $3$ out of $8$ lucky draw prizes from a pool of $650$ tickets? Each ticket can only win the prize once.

I figured the probability of the $6$ tickets winning $1$ prize out of $8$ would be:

$$
1 - \frac{\binom{644}{8}}{\binom{650}{8}} = 1 - \frac{110716976272} {119291579325} \approx 0.07188.
$$

But I’m not really sure how to calculate the probability of them winning $3$ out of $8$ prizes.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show your attempt and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: no thinking, actually wondering what’s the answer, my group of 6 people actually won 3 out of 8 lucky draw prizes so wondering what are the odds of that.

Comment: "no thinking" is not the way this site work.

Comment: understood, added my thinking and attempt

Answer (score 1):

You have total $650$ options, out of which you chose $6$. The number of ways of doing this are $\binom{650}{6}$.

For exactly $3$ winnings, you should have $3$ out of $8$ and the rest $3$ should be from other $642$.

$$P(E) = \frac{\dbinom{642}{3}\dbinom{8}{3}}{\dbinom{650}{6}}$$

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can use `$\binom{n}{k}$` to obtain $\binom{n}{k}$.